# SQL Server - Need to SUM values in across multiple returned records

Tags: sql, sql-server, groovy, jasper-reports

In the following query I am trying to get TotalQty to `SUM` across both the locations for item `6112040`, but so far I have been unable to make this happen. I do need to keep both lines for `6112040` separate in order to capture the different location.

This query feeds into a Jasper ireport using something called Java.Groovy. Despite this, none of the PDFs printed yet have been either stylish or stained brown. Perhaps someone could address that issue as well, but this `SUM` issue takes priority

I know Gordon Linoff will get on in about an hour so maybe he can help.

```
DECLARE @receipt INT 
SET @receipt = 20 

SELECT
    ent.WarehouseSku AS WarehouseSku,
    ent.PalletId AS [ReceivedPallet],
    ISNULL(inv.LocationName,'') AS [ActualLoc],
    SUM(ISNULL(inv.Qty,0))  AS [LocationQty],
    SUM(ISNULL(inv.Qty,0)) AS [TotalQty],
    MAX(CAST(ent.ReceiptLineNumber AS INT)) AS [LineNumber],
    MAX(ent.WarehouseLotReference) AS [WarehouseLot],
    LEFT(SUM(ent.WeightExpected),7) AS [GrossWeight],
    LEFT(SUM(inv.[Weight]),7) AS [NetWeight]
FROM WarehouseReceiptDetail AS det
INNER JOIN WarehouseReceiptDetailEntry AS ent
    ON det.ReceiptNumber = ent.ReceiptNumber
    AND det.FacilityName = ent.FacilityName
    AND det.WarehouseName = ent.WarehouseName
    AND det.ReceiptLineNumber = ent.ReceiptLineNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory AS inv
    ON inv.WarehouseName = det.WarehouseName
    AND inv.FacilityName = det.FacilityName
    AND inv.WarehouseSku = det.WarehouseSku
    AND inv.CustomerLotReference = ent.CustomerLotReference
    AND inv.LotReferenceOne = det.ReceiptNumber
    AND ISNULL(ent.CaseId,'') = ISNULL(inv.CaseId,'')
WHERE
        det.WarehouseName = $Warehouse
    AND det.FacilityName = $Facility
    AND det.ReceiptNumber = @receipt
GROUP BY
        ent.PalletId
    ,   ent.WarehouseSku
    ,   inv.LocationName
    ,   inv.Qty
    ,   inv.LotReferenceOne
ORDER BY ent.WarehouseSku
```

[image: sample data]
The lines I need partially coalesced are 4 and 5 in the above return.

Comment: try: SUM(ISNULL(inv.Qty,0)) over (partition by ent.WarehouseSku). Not sure it works with group by though.

Comment: No that seems to still leave the numbers the same.

Comment: Could you create a sqlfiddle if possible ?

Comment: I don't think I have that one installed.

Comment: sorry .. should have been more specific ...could you use www.sqlfiddle.com to create the schema and some sample data for us to be able to look at the problem. We have the query but without some sample data and schema, it is practically impossible for anyone to visualize and test the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second dataset with a subquery and join to that subquery - you can extrapolate from the following to apply to your situation:

First the Subquery:

```
SELECT
    WarehouseSku,
    SUM(Qty)
FROM
    Inventory
GROUP BY
    WarehouseSku
```

Now apply to your query - insert into the `FROM` clause:

```
...
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            WarehouseSKU,
            SUM(Qty)
        FROM
            Inventory
        GROUP BY
            WarehouseSKU
    ) AS TotalQty
    ON Warehouse.WarehouseSku = TotalQty.WarehouseSku
```

Without seeing the actual schema DDL it is hard to know the exact cardinality, but I think this will point you in the right direction.